# onResume and onPause loop when device in sleepmode?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, sleep-mode

When i put my device in sleep mode (lockscreen), the logcat gets flooded with calls to `onPause` and `onResume` this keeps looping and my broadcastreceivers keep getting unregistered and registered, it stops when i go back to the app.

Is this normal?

**My Code**

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (getActivity()!= null){
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(UpdateDataSetBroadCastReceiver);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "AlbumsFragment OnPause Called!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerUpdateDataSetBroadCastReceiver();
        Log.i(TAG,"AlbumsFragment OnResume Called!");
    }
```

Comment: Hey Vince, quick question or two; what device are you testing with, and have you tested with both emulator and physical devices? I'm curious as to whether the behaviour is replicated between the two

Comment: What is your Fragment's container? Is it directly within the activity?

Comment: @SammyT Yes and i'm using a viewpager which has 5 fragments.

Comment: @TomLarcher Happens on both

Comment: Nvm just tested it and not happening on an emulator, could the cause be my physical device which runs a custom rom?

Comment: @Vince since the issue seems to affect physical devices only, I'd then rule out your custom rom by testing on another physical device if you have one. While I don't think it's a wakelock causing this issue for you, I suspect there might be something waking your app when default behaviour would be for it to sleep (and hence a normal flow Activity Lifecycle events)

Answer (score 0):

In onPause method you should first unregister recievers, call other methods (for example Log.i) and afterwards call super.onPause().